# How can I create a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I've wanted to make a YouTube channel for a while now.  I made a Google account as required. Yet whenever I click on the "Create a channel" button, nothing happens!

It's not like the screen freezes, but it just doesn't load. Mind you I have a new computer, so could somebody please tell me what might be the problem? Do I need any additional software or something?

Comment: Do you have any adblocking or other extensions on your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting http://youtube.com/create_channel directly. It will redirect you to the Create Channel page.

Answer (score -3):

Login to Google and click on YouTube you will be automatically signed in to YouTube then click on my channel in the menu that's it. You will be redirected to create channel process

Comment: That would be helpful, that doesn't work, that's what I'm saying